# Is it possible to use format! in Substrate runtime?

Tags: frame

From the [link](https://docs.rs/sp-std/2.0.0-rc3/sp_std/fmt/index.html), It seems format! can work in [Substrate](https://substrate.io/) runtime.

```
let hello_world = sp_std::fmt::format!("Hello,{}","world");
```

I want to have a variable `hello_world` and use it for latter。

But I always get an error : could not find `format` in `fmt`

I have searched for a long time, I also refs: [how to use format! in no_std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200268/how-can-i-use-the-format-macro-in-a-no-std-environment)

I have been confused for several days.

The [link](https://docs.rs/sp-std/2.0.0-rc3/sp_std/fmt/index.html) is not correct? Are there some stories behind this?

Comment: Hello @NukeManDan , Could you please help me?

Answer (score 9):

The item referred by the path `sp_std::fmt::format` is actually a function, rather than a macro. See [documentation](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_std/fmt/fn.format.html).

The fundamental problem though is that under a `no_std` environment, the `format!` macro doesn't exist, as it requires allocating a `String`, which is a struct that only exists in `std`.

Thus, you won't be able to use the `format!` macro in the Substrate runtime. The documentation that you see on that page is simply showing you the docs from the standard library, as you can see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html); there's no difference between what you're reading and the stdlib's documentation page on the `fmt` module.

In addition, Rust macros are always hoisted up to the crate-level, rather than staying in the module in which they are defined. This means that if the `format!` macro existed, then the proper way to reference it would be `sp_std::format!` instead of `sp_std::fmt::format!`.

Answer (score 9):

Using `String` in the runtime is discouraged by Substrate, because it most often means that you are doing something "wrong". Aka user data should not be stored on chain, you should instead store a hash of the data.

Nevertheless, it is still possible to access a `String` or even `format!`. Format is for example available using `sp_std::alloc::format!()`.